# Interpreting loss in LSTM tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am using PTB dataset to predict next words.
My code : [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/5VMfLrwR).
The input to the model (Batch_input) are the words with vocabulary_size of 10000. All the outputs (Batch_labels) are one-hot encoded as you can see a sample in the part of output code below.
Following is my output after training the LSTM Model. 
Output : [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/q8z2ktn8).

Following is some part of output :

```
Initialized
('Loss :', 9.2027139663696289)
('Batch_input :', array([9971, 9972, 9974, 9975, 9976, 9980, 9981, 9982, 9983, 9984, 9986,
       9987, 9988, 9989, 9991, 9992, 9993, 9994, 9995, 9996, 9997, 9998,
       9999,    2, 9256,    1,    3,   72,  393,   33, 2133,    0,  146,
         19,    6, 9207,  276,  407,    3,    2,   23,    1,   13,  141,
          4,    1, 5465,    0, 3081, 1596,   96,    2, 7682,    1,    3,
         72,  393,    8,  337,  141,    4, 2477,  657, 2170], dtype=int32))
('Batch_labels :', array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ...,
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32))
Average loss at step 0: 0.092027 learning rate: 1.000000
('Label: ', array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ...,
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32))
('Predicted:', array([[-0.36508381, -0.25612   , -0.26035795, ..., -0.42688274,
        -0.4078168 , -0.36345699],
       [-0.46035308, -0.27282876, -0.34078932, ..., -0.50623679,
        -0.47014061, -0.43237451],
       [-0.14694197, -0.07506246, -0.10392818, ..., -0.1128526 ,
        -0.12404554, -0.13495158],
       ...,
       [-0.07286638, -0.04560997, -0.05932444, ..., -0.08352474,
        -0.07679331, -0.07829094],
       [-0.13576414, -0.07057529, -0.1017022 , ..., -0.11192483,
        -0.14713599, -0.11757012],
       [-0.05446544, -0.02738103, -0.03401792, ..., -0.05073205,
        -0.03746928, -0.05750648]], dtype=float32))
================================================================================
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
8605
('f', u'altman')
('as', u'altman')
('feed', array([8605]))
('Sentence :', u'altman rake years regatta memotec pierre <unk> nonexecutive as will <eos> ssangyong director nahb group the cluett rubens snack-food fromstein calloway and memotec a board years regatta publishing fields rake group group rake cluett ssangyong pierre calloway memotec gitano gold rubens as as director sim is publishing gitano punts join <unk> and a old punts years memotec a rake is guterman cluett ssangyong will berlitz nahb <eos> of group join <unk> board join and pierre consolidated board cluett dutch gold as ipo ssangyong guterman a kia will dutch and director centrust consolidated rudolph guterman guterman cluett years n.v. old board rubens ')
================================================================================
('Loss :', 496.78199882507323)
('Batch_input :', array([4115,    5,   14,   45,   55,    3,   72,  195, 1244,  220,    2,
          0, 3150, 7426,    1,   13, 4052,    1,  496,   14, 6885,    0,
          1,   22,  113, 2652, 8068,    5,   14, 2474, 5250,   10,  464,
         52, 3004,  466, 1244,   15,    2,    1,   80,    0,  167,    4,
         35, 2645,    1,   65,   10,  558, 6092, 3574, 1898,  666,    1,
          7,   27,    1, 4241, 6036,    7,    3,    2,  366], dtype=int32))
('Batch_labels :', array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ...,
       [ 0.,  0.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32))
Average loss at step 100: 4.967820 learning rate: 1.000000
('Label: ', array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ...,
       [ 0.,  0.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32))
('Predicted:', array([[  4.41551352e+00,   9.98007679e+00,   1.75690575e+01, ...,
          6.83443546e+00,  -2.30797195e+00,   1.73750782e+00],
       [  1.26826172e+01,   5.96618652e-03,   1.18247871e+01, ...,
         -3.70885038e+00,  -8.55356884e+00,  -9.16959190e+00],
       [  1.44652233e+01,   5.12977028e+00,   9.42045784e+00, ...,
          1.39444172e+00,   1.95213389e+00,  -4.00810099e+00],
       ...,
       [  2.93052626e+00,   9.41266441e+00,   1.79130135e+01, ...,
          4.24245834e+00,  -1.46551771e+01,  -3.35697136e+01],
       [  2.48945675e+01,   2.32091904e+01,   2.47276134e+01, ...,
         -6.39845896e+00,  -2.66628218e+00,  -4.59843445e+00],
       [  1.34414902e+01,   4.80197811e+00,   1.89214745e+01, ...,
         -5.91268682e+00,  -8.80736637e+00,  -6.49542713e+00]], dtype=float32))
================================================================================
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
3619
('f', u'officially')
('as', u'officially')
('feed', array([3619]))
('Sentence :', u'officially <unk> to <eos> filters ago cigarettes is that cigarette stopped to <eos> researchers <unk> to <eos> filters ago cigarettes asbestos the filters ago cigarettes asbestos the filters ago cigarettes is that cigarette up the <eos> researchers to <eos> researchers <unk> to <eos> filters ago cigarettes asbestos the filters ago cigarettes asbestos <eos> filters ago cigarettes asbestos the filters ago cigarettes is that cigarette up the <eos> researchers <unk> to <eos> researchers <unk> to <eos> filters ago cigarettes asbestos of percentage years the the the <eos> researchers <unk> to <eos> filters ago cigarettes asbestos the filters ago cigarettes asbestos the filters ')
================================================================================
```

The initial loss is 0.92  which predicts the text as given.The next loss is around 4.57 at 100 step. But as the `number of step increases loss increases` which is anomaly (right?). 
And also the next predicted word in output `'among' repeats at step 500`. 
Is there any error in training?
This is new output I get : [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/Q9pud7w9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure about the problem in your code but I noticed that you start the learning rate at 1.

> `learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(1.0, global_step, 5000, 0.1, staircase=True)`

Try to pick a lower initial value.

High learning rates causes the model weights to take long leaps so it may miss the minimum and it may even reach a point where the loss is higher (which may be your case). it is like super-jumping over a valley from one side to the other instead of going down into it.

[image: Learning rate effect on loss curve]

Reference for the image: http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/

Lowering the learning rate from 1e-2 to 1e-4 solved a similar problem in a different model. Your model may work at a different learning rate.

Comment: thanks .. yeah achieved a different result some random words ... definitely not the repeating once.So, decreasing 1 to 1e-4 helped.